# verify a boolean condition inside a function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have written a PostgreSQL function containing a while statement like:

```
WHILE id_exist == 'f' LOOP
    lotto_id = lotto_id + 1;
    id_exist = check_if_exist(lotto_id, 'lotto', 'id');
END LOOP;
```

Where `id_exist` is a boolean variable initialized by calling `check_if_exist()` method (used also inside while code) that returned a boolean value.

Now when I try to call my function, I get this error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean == unknown
LINE 1: SELECT id_exist == 'f'
                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add
explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT id_exist == 'f'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "acquistolotto" line 11 at WHILE
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator is a single equals sign ("=", not "==")

Also, did you set a value to id_exist before you entered the loop?

Comment: ok, that's right. But now i've a infinite loop problem. I'll open another question. thanks

Sure, i've set that value calling check_if_exist() function out of the while

Comment: If that's the case, it looks like your check_if_exist() function is always returning "false."   Take a look at that, first.